# Mount directory using docker-compose or dockerfile (without copying)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im trying to move my Owncloud instance to docker. I have a "server" with 120GB root, and 500GB usb disk designated for owncloud data. I came up with such configuration:

```
    docker-owncloud
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mysql
│   ├── db <- mysql files
│   └── Dockerfile
└── owncloud
    ├── data <- owncloud files (300GB)
    └── Dockerfile
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    owncloud:
        build: owncloud
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./owncloud/data:/var/www/html
    mysql:
        build: mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
        volumes:
            - ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Mysql dockerfile:

```
from mysql:5.7.17
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV TZ=Europe/Warsaw
```

Owncloud dockerfile:

```
FROM owncloud:9.1.4-apache
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV TZ=Europe/Warsaw
```

Now if I do "docker-compose build", data from owncloud/data (300GB) is being copied to new volume, which is impossible because I don't have such amount of free disk space. 
 
Is there a way to mount those two directories using docker-compose or dockerfile without copying the data? Is there any other known way of dealing with such situation ?

I have spend more that 3 hours finding that this is impossible, but I can't believe that it is the case. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: what makes you think the data is being copied instead of mounted?  what you've posted should work as expected

Comment: When I do docker-compose build command, it last very long for owncloud, and I can see in "df -h" as free space on / decrease.

Comment: same thing happen with `docker-compose up owncloud`?

Comment: I will try it after I return to my home. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I tried "docker-compose up owncloud" and i give up after 40GB of my / free space was consumed.

Comment: You'll have to troubleshoot it.  Try removing the volumes from the compose file.  Try the equivalent docker commands from the cli. Try the 2 containers by themselves. FWIW I still don't believe the data is being copied by docker.  I was able to mount a dir on a usb drive into a container using `docker run -d -v /path/to/dir:/mnt nginx`

Comment: Your docker compose is using the build command instead of image, try using image instead.  Build creates a whole new image everytime which explains the copying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build, docker is sending all the files in the current directory and subdirectories to the daemon. You know this as the context.

You have 2 options:

- Move the data directory outside of the directory structure where you're building the images.
- create a .dockerignore file and add the data directory

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage